# Discord.js command handler aliases (discord.js v13)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i want to set a command handler aliases, but the bot is doesn't response.

in ping.js ===

```
module.exports = {
name: 'ping',
aliases: ['pong'],
execute(message, client) {
    message.reply('pong!')
    }
}
```

How i can set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to make certain changes in your command handler as well! the suitable changes you need to make would be:

- Making it in your execute function so it can find and execute aliases too!

```js
const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));
command.execute(message,client);
```

Your definitions of `command` and `commandName` may vary so I suggest refering to your own code and making suitable changes rather than copy pasting.